# test for difference between means of two non-normal distributions (poisson or negative binomial)

Tags: inference

I want to test for the difference between means for what I think are two negative binomial or poisson-like distributions that are 0 inflated.

Can I rely on the law of large numbers to do a simple t -test? Or , is this going to be unreliable given the data type?

My data are graphed below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please, do not rely on the law of large numbers to do a simple *t*-test. The more non-normal your data are, the larger the sample size required. It seems like you have under 3000, but your data are really really non-normal.

You can do both: a [zero-inflated negative binomial (ZINB) model](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/zinb/) has fewer restrictions than a [zero-inflated Poisson (ZIP) model](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/zip/). If the results differ substantively, then you can attempt to investigate why. If your variance is much larger than the mean, then the ZINB model would be more reliable than the ZIP model.

Comment: Ok! This sounds appropriate then. To specify the ZINB model to find group differences, would I use my numeric data as my response, and group as an IV?  For example, I could specify the model in R as:  m1 <- zeroinfl(Response ~ Group,
               data = test, dist = "negbin", EM = TRUE)   , and then if the Group variable is significant, I could conclude that there is a mean difference?

Comment: Yes, you would.